# C program to partitition a simply linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, partition, compare-and-swap

so i've been working on a small function(part of a bigger program) that basically does the following:
define a list and the number of elements N, then input N elements. after this, input a value X;
I have to 'split' / re-order the list in a way so that its elements with value < X are in the beginning, in their relative order and the ones with higher value than X come after; eg.:

```
Input:
list 6
2 5 6 4 3 1
X 3

Output:
2 3 1 5 6 4
```

my code and list structure are down below:
(the partition function is at the bottom, just above the main function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 64

typedef struct ll_node_t
{
    void* data;
    struct ll_node_t* next;
} ll_node_t;

typedef struct linked_list_t
{
    ll_node_t* head;
    unsigned int data_size;
    unsigned int size;
} linked_list_t;

linked_list_t*
ll_create(unsigned int data_size)
{
    linked_list_t* list = malloc(sizeof(list));
    // err handle
    
    list->head = NULL;
    list->data_size = data_size;
    list->size = 0;

    return list;
}

void
ll_add_nth_node(linked_list_t* list, unsigned int n, const void* new_data)
{
    if(n < 0) exit(0);

    ll_node_t* new_node = malloc(sizeof(ll_node_t*));
    new_node->data = malloc(list->data_size);
    // err handle

    memcpy(new_node->data, new_data, list->data_size);
    
    if(n == 0  || list->size == 0) { 
        new_node->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_node;
        list->size++;
        return;
    }   

    if(n < list->size)
    {
        ll_node_t* current = list->head;

        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
        list->size++;

        return;
    }

    if(n >= list->size)
    {
        ll_node_t* current = list->head;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < list->size - 1; i++)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
        list->size++;

        return;
    }
}


ll_node_t*
ll_remove_nth_node(linked_list_t* list, unsigned int n)
{
    if(n < 0) exit(0);

    ll_node_t* removedNode = NULL;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        removedNode = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        list->size--;

        return removedNode;
    }

    if(n < list->size)
    {

        ll_node_t* current = list->head;
        // err handle

        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        removedNode = current->next;
        current->next = current->next->next;
        list->size--;

        return removedNode;
    }

    if(n >= list->size)
    {
        ll_node_t* current = list->head;
        // err handle

        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        removedNode = current->next;
        current->next = NULL;
        list->size--;

        return removedNode;
    }
}

unsigned int
ll_get_size(linked_list_t* list)
{
    return list->size;
}

void
ll_free(linked_list_t** pp_list)
{
    ll_node_t* current = (*pp_list)->head;

    for(int i = 0; i < (*pp_list)->size; i++)
    {
        (*pp_list)->head = current->next;
        free(current->data);
        free(current);
        current = (*pp_list)->head;

    }

    free(*pp_list);
}

void
ll_print_int(linked_list_t* list)
{
    if(!list->size) exit(0);
    ll_node_t* current = list->head;

    for(int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(int*)current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void
ll_print_string(linked_list_t* list)
{
    if(!list->size) exit(0);

    ll_node_t* current = list->head;

    for(int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", (char*)current->data);

        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void partition(linked_list_t* list, int x)
{
    ll_node_t* current = list->head;
    ll_node_t* tail = list->head;

    for(int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    //special case for the first element of the list
    if(*(int*)current->data > x)
    {
        tail->next = current;
        list->head = current->next;

        tail = current;
    }
    
    // loop that finds elements > X
    for(int i = 0; i < list->size - 1; i++)
    {   
        if(*(int*)current->data > x)
        {
            // assigning the element to the end
            tail->next = current->next;

            // linking the previous element to the one after the element
            current->next = current->next->next;

            tail = tail->next;
            tail->next = NULL;

            // moving on to next element
            current = current->next;
        }
        else current = current->next;
        // moving on to next element 
    }
}

int main()
{
    linked_list_t* linkedList;

    while (1) {
        char command[16];
        long size, num;

        scanf("%s", command);

        if (strcmp(command, "list") == 0) {
            linkedList = ll_create(sizeof(int));
            scanf("%ld", &size);

            long int curr_nr;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                scanf("%ld", &curr_nr);
                ll_add_nth_node(linkedList, size, &curr_nr);
            }
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "X") == 0) {
            scanf("%ld", &num);

            partition(linkedList, num);
            ll_print_int(linkedList);
            break;
        }
    }

    ll_free(&linkedList);

    return 0;
}
```

so since i have list size as well, which is the number of elements in the list i thought the following:

before looping through the list, check if the head(first element) needs to be shifted at the end (if > X) and then have a loop that loops list->size - 1 times and when the condition inside is met, do the following:

it'd basically loop through elements and look at their next's, so when an element's next is > X, it would be shifted:
assign the tail's next element to be the element > X(current->next), then link current elements next to the one after the element. after that the new tail would be the element that was added at the end.

currently I get a Segmentation fault at the first line inside the condition in the for loop, on this line:
`tail->next = current->next;`

disclaimer: the main program, as i've tested it, works just fine for adding elements, and so on.

Comment: The `malloc` sizes are wrong. `malloc(sizeof(list))` this allocates enough for one pointer, and so does this `malloc(sizeof(ll_node_t*))`. Should be `malloc(sizeof(*list))` and `malloc(sizeof(ll_node_t))`.

Comment: Initializing the list with a data width of `sizeof (int)` and then reading and inserting data as `long int` has the potential to cause issues on systems where `sizeof (long int) != sizeof (int)`.

Comment: Note: this code snippet misses the mark slightly on being *minimal* and *reproducible* (see: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). It would be helpful to create an example that focuses on implementing the partitioning algorithm, by removing the excess code (printing / removal functions, variable sized data, user input), and providing static "input" to setup the program state. Questions with smaller, complete programs are much more likely to receive help here.

Comment: It might be simpler to create two lists, one for nodes <= X, the other for nodes > X, keeping track of the head and tail nodes for each list. When this is done, set first list tail node next pointer to second list head node, and second list tail node next pointer to null (if second list head is null), then nothing to do after setting first list tail next pointer). Even if you "move" nodes within the list, using two tail pointers would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I going to offer an answer that is not exactly a solution to your existing code, but instead presents a different way of thinking about organizing your data as you work through it.

What if, instead of trying to reorder the list in place (managing head, current, and tail) while iterating through it, we *deconstruct* the list and *construct* two new lists? Our result becomes the concatenation of these two lists.

Visualized in pseudocode this would work like:

```
Q is [2 5 6 4 3 1]

part Q <= 3
    L is []     
    R is []
 
    Q eql [2 5 6 4 3 1]
           ^ -> L eql [2]
    Q eql [5 6 4 3 1]
           ^ -> R eql [5]
    Q eql [6 4 3 1]
           ^ -> R eql [5 6]
    Q eql [4 3 1]  
           ^ -> R eql [5 6 4]
    Q eql [3 1]    
           ^ -> L eql [2 3]
    Q eql [1]
           ^ -> L eql [2 3 1]
    Q eql []
    Q is L concat R
    Q eql [2 3 1 5 6 4]
```

By doing this, our partitioning function gets utilize the same logic we used to build our list in the first place.

Here is an example of what this might look like in C, using a very simple linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int value;
} node;

typedef struct {
    node *head;
} list;

void list_append_node(list *l, node *n) {
    node *root = l->head;

    if (root) {
        while (root->next)
            root = root->next;
        root->next = n;
    } else
        l->head = n;
}

void list_append_value(list *l, int v) {
    node *n = calloc(1, sizeof *n);

    n->value = v;
    list_append_node(l, n);
}

void list_part(list *l, int v) {
    list lower = { 0 };
    list upper = { 0 };

    for (node *curr = l->head, *temp; curr; curr = temp) {
        temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = NULL;
        list_append_node(curr->value <= v ? &lower : &upper, curr);
    }

    list_append_node(&lower, upper.head);
    l->head = lower.head;
}

int main(void) {
    int inputs[] = { 2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1 };
    size_t len = sizeof inputs / sizeof *inputs;

    list l = { 0 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        list_append_value(&l, inputs[i]);

    list_part(&l, 3);

    for (node *n = l.head, *t; n; n = t) {
        t = n->next;
        printf("%d ", n->value);
        free(n);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

`stdout`:

```
2 3 1 5 6 4
```

---

Note, the use of a `node *tail` member for each list could be implemented to improve the performance of `list_append_node` from O(N) to O(1).