# How to split a linked list with a cutting value?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I successfully implemented a function but with a minor bug I can't figure out. The function filter() takes in a list. It is expected to put all elements below a value into a new list.

```
LIST *filter(LIST *lst, int value) {
    LIST *new_list = createlist();
    NODE *p = lst->front;
    NODE *p1 = NULL;
    NODE *p2 = NULL;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->val <= value) {
            if (lengthlist(new_list) == 0) {
                new_list->front = newd_list->back = p;
                p1 = new_list->back;
            } else {
                new_list->back = p;
                p1->next = p;
                p1 = new_list->back;
            }
        } else {
            if (lst->front->val <= value) {
                lst->front = lst->back = p;
                p2 = lst->back;
            } else {
                lst->back = p;
                p2->next = p;
                p2 = lst->back;
            }
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return new_list;
}
```

Comment: Start by just creating functions that add or remove nodes from a linked list. Don't do it all in one function.

Comment: I'm bound to reuse the nodes by only changing their "next"s...no adding or removing nodes

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640719/2505965) I gave yesterday to a *very* similar question, which you could adapt to your needs (instead of concatenating the lists, assign one's head to the existing list, and return the other as a dynamic allocation).

Comment: @swoosh Modifying a couple of `next` *is* adding to or removing nodes from linked lists. I'm not talking about allocating or deallocating nodes.

Comment: After the line `NODE *p = lst->front`, you need to clear `lst`, so that it starts as an empty list, just like `returned_list`. Then the code for both lists should be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` member of a back node of either "new" list is not always being set to NULL, instead still pointing to an old node.

In `[4, 9, 2, 4, 8, 12, 7, 3]` becoming `[9, 8, 12, 7, 3]` and `[4, 2, 4, 3]` we can see what should be the last node of the first list, `7`, still points to its old `next` member, `3`.

This happens because `p = p->next;` needs `p` to retain its `next` member through the prior body of the loop, relying on some subsequent iteration to overwrite that information (when accessed as a `back` node).

Another way of thinking about it: One of the lists is always implicitly `NULL` terminated, since some node had to be the end of the original list. The other list points into this `NULL` terminated list somewhere.

```
[9, 8, 12, 7, _]                    
           |
           V
 [4, 2, 4, 3]
```

---

An easier way to reason about this is to first create a function that adds nodes to a list.

```
void append(LIST *list, NODE *node) {
    if (list->front) 
        list->back->next = node;
    else                      
        list->front = node;
    
    list->back = node;
}
```

The filter function then resets the existing list, after taking the front node.

For each node, we save the `next` value for the following iteration, and then reset it to `NULL`, for the case when it is the last node to be added to a list.

Then it is just matter of adding it to the correct list.

```
LIST *filter(LIST *lst, int value) { 
    LIST *returned_list = lst_create();
    NODE *node = lst->front; 
    lst->front = ls->back = NULL;
    
    for (NODE *temp; node; node = temp) {
        temp = node->next;
        
        node->next = NULL;
                                    
        if (node->value <= value)   
            append(returned_list, node);
        else
            append(lst, node);
    }                                            
    
    return returned_list;
}
```

Comment: Hi Oka, your solution works and it makes sense to me, but can you explain further what is this for loop doing for (NODE *temp; node; node = temp) {}....I just started c programming and I never seen this before

Comment: Simply another way of expressing `NODE *temp; while (node) { /* ... */ node = temp; }`, where `temp` is scoped to the `for` loop, instead of the surrounding block. See: [for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for)